# Access image file from Laravel API to Vue Cli 3

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js

I have a Laravel API for my backend and Vue Cli 3 for my front end. I am trying to access images from storage/app/avatars - Laravel to my front end Vue. So far I've done php artisan storage:link and it created a shortcut folder to my public. I have this in my controller [User Controller show function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1HD.png)

User Controller show function:

[image]

Here is a return response from postman :

[image]

when I open the link either thru browser or postman i get response 404 not found :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel `Storage::url()` user `.env` `APP_URL`  to generate url

so you need to fix

in
.env

```sh
APP_URL=localhost:8000
```

then run
`php artisan config:clear`

ref link https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6d082c81e5bf226dfa6d1dc030e69a225349f535/config/filesystems.php#L41

in this link you can see internally use of `APP_URL`

Comment: my APP_URL in .env is set to localhost what url should I put? it is deployed locally for now.

Comment: already did still no luck APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

Comment: still the same http://localhost/storage/avatars/60208a722a3f6-vvx.PNG

Comment: Affter setting APP_URL's domain:8000 i just did php artisan config:clear.. It already responded an image. Got it thanks!